# Is there a minimal browser specifically designed to prevent drive-by malware?

Tags: firefox, security, browser, malware, safe-browsing

After my father's PC (with Avast and Firefox configured to auto-update in the background) got infected, most probably via a drive-by download, by a ransomware, I was wondering how I could prevent that in the future, both for him and for me.

I am using Firefox 47.0.1 on Windows 7 x64.

So my question is: **is there a way, when you know you are visiting a potentially hazardous link, to open this link in a dedicated "malware-hardened" minimal browser, or version of your browser?**

I know of Noscript, of deactivating all plugins and always asking to enable the remaining ones, deactivating pdf in browser and so on. What I would like is an additional layer of protection. So there are five points:

1. If I have a blank javascript whitelist in this "hardened browser", then does Noscript really successfully block all Javascript-borne threats? i.e. does it prevent any script from actually being fetched from the internet and cached locally, leaving only the bare HTML page being downloaded to your memory?
2. Among all image formats, which formats are absolutely positively impossible to exploit? I have seen the [WMF vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Metafile_vulnerability), so WMF is not on that whitelist, but what image formats are?
3. based on (2), is there a way (in Firefox or another browser) to allow only the white-listed image formats to be fetched and displayed?
4. Is running the browser in a virtual machine the ultimate answer? Are there any known cases of "mass-market" malware (i.e. outside of [security lab tests](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2015/05/14/the-venom-virtual-machine-escape-bug-what-you-need-to-know/)) that could break through VMWare or similar virtualization software and infect the host PC?
5. Finally, is there a browser specifically designed to be so minimal and hardened, that it simply cannot load anything that could execute as malware? I understand such a browser would probably only display text and links, and maybe a few simple images; that's fine with me though. I just want to be able to view text pages, with text positioned properly (i.e. at least some part of CSS must still be working) with links in them, and yet be safe of everything it could load. I can go back to web 0.5 if it allows me to be as secure as an air-gaped machine is from online threats...

Thank you very much!

Comment: No, as these vulnerabilities change week to week as they are discovered in all browsers. Its a cat and mouse game. There is no bullet proof way to be 100% safe.

Comment: Chromium on OpenBSD (with W^X, pledge) is probably your best bet

Comment: @MOAB I was thinking "best defense is not to use", like air-gaped against online attacks. So if so many things are deactivated but the rest is regularly maintained it should, like they call it, "decrease the attack surface". Hence Lynx in Wes Sayeed's answer.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan: yep you're right this seems hard to break too! I wonder though, which of {OpenBSD + Chromium} and {regular Windows + OpenBSD on VM + up to date Firefox} (with Noscript in both cases) is stronger...or maybe a VM running OpenBSD inside an OpenBSD? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there is no "automated" system of hardening your browser when doing potentially risky things other than the mechanisms you're already familiar with.  If such a system did exist, it would get exploited within some time and then we'd be right back where we started again.  So you see where this is going.  It's a point/counterpoint game with security systems trying to keep malware off your machine, and malware writers getting ever more clever by the day.

The most important thing people need to realize is that the biggest exploit on any computer system is the user.  In your father's case, it's possible that he *might* have been a victim of a drive-by download, but it's *far* more likely that he was simply tricked into downloading the virus himself.  Finding and exploiting software vulnerabilities is hard.  Lying to people is much easier and much more effective from the malware writer's point of view.

There are only two things that are tried-and-true measures for keeping your computer virus-free:

- Keep all your software patched and up-to-date.
- Keep yourself educated and be smarter than the malware.

There are simply no substitutes to these two things.  If you fall behind in either then it really doesn't matter what kind of malware protection you have.

---

Now, to address your questions specifically:

> 1. If I have a blank javascript whitelist in this "hardened browser", then does Noscript really successfully block all Javascript-borne threats?

Absolutely it does.  If you have not whitelisted a domain, then client-side javascripts from that domain do not run, period.  Bear in mind, however, that NoScript does not run on a per-tab basis.  If you whitelist a domain, then javascripts from that domain will run in all your tabs.

> 2. Among all image formats, which formats are absolutely positively impossible to exploit? I have seen the WMF vulnerability, so WMF is not on that whitelist, but what image formats are?

This is a tough one; technically, all of them are, and none of them are.  Every media format (audio, video, and images) has metadata in it.  The metadata is *supposed* to be for embedding information *about* the file into the file itself (example: EXIF data in a `.jpg` or `.tif` file, or the album/artist/track info in an `.mp3`'s ID3 tag).  Only a colossal idiot would write a media viewer/player that can execute the metadata as if it were program code.  That idiot, as it turns out, is Microsoft, and there is absolutely no excuse for it.  I don't know what they were thinking (probably has something to do with DRM crap), but Microsoft *created* that exploit in the first place during a dark time when they literally thought they could "own" the Internet.  I don't know what to tell you here other than to stick with open-source software that doesn't do stupid things like executing a data stream.

> 3. Based on (2), is there a way (in Firefox or another browser) to allow only the white-listed image formats to be fetched and displayed?

No.  All the common image formats (.jpg, .gif, and .png) are "vulnerable" per the explanation given above.  Again, Firefox or Chromium should save you here (I personally don't trust IE or Chrome).  Other formats such as .pdf, Flash, Silverlight, Java, etc. are proprietary and are *definitely* vulnerable because they are closed-source and you have to rely on Adobe, Oracle, and Microsoft to patch exploits found in them.  For these, you can just disable the plugin(s) that enable those features or use a blocker that makes you jump though a hoop to display their content.

> 4. Is running the browser in a virtual machine the ultimate answer? Are there any known cases of "mass-market" malware (i.e. outside of security lab tests) that could break through VMWare or similar virtualization software and infect the host PC?

It's not the "ultimate" answer, but it's a much safer way to browse for the uber-paranoid.  A VM is a sandbox from which very few processes can escape.  The only two attack vectors are network-based exploits (ones that search for other computers on your network), and attacks on the VM "tools" software itself.  Both can be mitigated by using the "isolation mode" feature that all VM products have.  Also use a snapshot of a known clean configuration.  If you infect the VM with a virus, all you have to do is revert the snapshot to get rid of it.  Note that you will have to refresh the snapshot from time to time as you install updates/patches.

> 5. Finally, is there a browser specifically designed to be so minimal and hardened, that it simply cannot load anything that could execute as malware?

None like you're thinking that will make web browsing a useful activity.  Lynx is a popular text-only browser.  It does not support images or plugins of any kind.  Unfortunately, it's only an acceptable alternative if you're partying like it's 1989.  You could also use a Linux Live distro that runs entirely off a CD or USB flash drive.  There are many out there.  But you'd have to reboot your computer every time you wanted to browse the Internet.  Really, there's no practical answer to this question.

On my personal computer, I run Firefox with 5 separate condoms wrapped around it.  NoScript, Ghostery, AdBlock Plus, BetterPrivacy, and Self-Destructing Cookies.  I've also tweaked a bunch of privacy settings as well.  Using that many layers of security and maintaining whitelists for everything is a hassle.  I do it because I work in cybersecurity for a living and my whole life is lived under a figurative aluminum foil hat that I wear everywhere I go.  But I would never foist such a configuration on an unsophisticated user like your father.  If you don't know exactly what you're doing, these plugins make the Internet practically impossible to use at worst, and no better than an unprotected browser at best.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the point by point answer. In the case of my father, except if the malware had a "delay" time before activating, or modified the NTFS file modification times or Firefox history (which does not seem true since both are coherent), the encryption happened at a time when he was watching football (matches that do not air in his country) through Sopcast...right after he found the Sopcast link on a website actually. I get your point on Noscript and others that have to be managed every day, I also had to. So no Sopcast for him (already done) and Lynx/ (FF+NS+good VM) for me!